# TypeError: string indices must be integers (Python)

Tags: python, json

I am trying to retrieve the 'id' value : ad284hdnn.

I am getting the following error : `TypeError: string indices must be integers`

```
data = response.json()
print data

for key in data['result']:
     print key['id']
```

Here is the json that is returned when print the data string.

```
{u'meta': {u'httpStatus': u'200 - OK', u'requestId': u'12345'}, u'result': {u'username': u'test@test.com', u'firstName': u'joe', u'lastName': u'bloggs', u'accountStatus': u'active', u'id': u'ad284hdnn'}}
```

Comment: You should check what `key` is

Comment: `data['result']['id']`, you don't need to iterate.

Comment: `key` is a string, not a dictionary. If all you wanted was the value for the `'id'` key, use `print data['result']['id']`, there is no need to loop.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`data['result']` is a dictionary. Iterating over `dict` means iterating over its keys. Therefore `key` variable stores a string. That's why `key['id']` raises `TypeError: string indices must be integers`.

Comment: How can we fix this?

Comment: @MeharFatimaKhan `for result in data['result'].values(): print(result['id'])`